# Why do some linux commands work with a "*" in a list of files but others do not?

Tags: linux, glob

why does, for instance,

```
ls -1 /path/to/something/data*data/file*.txt
```

work fine, while something like the following returns an error:

```
tar -xzvf *tar.gz
tar: evsClient-v.0.0.6.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: evsClient-v.0.0.7.tar.gz: Not found in archive
```

Comment: Because globbing is done by the shell, before starting the program.

Comment: FWIW, you can use `xargs` or a shell `for` loop to work around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-f` option to `tar` only expects one argument to specify the file to process. If using a glob expression as you have to `tar -xzvf` and there are multiple files that get expanded as a result, the files after the first one are taken to be regular arguments to `tar`, not an option argument to `-f`.

Since you are using `-x`, `tar` is in extraction mode, and it is taking the other files to be the name of files to be extracted from the archive that it is operating on.

Answer (score 2):

When `*` isn't quoted, any word containing it is treated as a shell pattern, which expands to a list of file names matching that pattern.

In your first example, the pattern expands to a list of existing files, which `ls` then dutifully displays.

In your second example, the pattern again expands to a list of matching files. However, only the first member of that list is treated as the argument to the `f` option. The remaining items are names of files you want to extract from the first one, which is not what you intended.

The general rule is that the pattern simply provides a list of file names; it's up to you to ensure that the resulting list of files is a correct set of arguments for the command you are running.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. In this case, I have only one more question: In practice, is there a way to know or expect which will be the case? For instance, is there a way I could know a priori that this would work for `scp`, but fail for `tar`?

Comment: You simply have to know what arguments your command expects. No command actually sees the `*`; the pattern is replaced by what it matches before the command is called. From the command's perspective, there is no difference between `ls foo*` and `ls foo.c foo.txt` if those are the only two matching files in the current directory.

Comment: OK, I do understand what you are saying, and I am taking that as a no. Thank you, I will now accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "*" is actually expanded by the shell and the resulting list of filenames are then presented as arguments to the command in question.

The "ls" command supports a list of file names and so does the "tar" command. But the signature of tar is:

```
tar option(s) archive_name file_name(s)
```

So - in your example I assume that the command line is expanded to:

```
tar -xzvf evsClient-v.0.0.5.tar.gz evsClient-v.0.0.6.tar.gz evsClient-v.0.0.7.tar.gz
```

giving you the error because the two latter archives cannot be extracted from the first.